# Pivotal GemFire: PDX serializer config in Spring Data GemFire

Tags: java, spring, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have created a GemFire cluster with 2 Locators, 2 cache servers and a "Customer" REPLICATE Region. (Domain object class is placed in classpath during server startup).

I am able to run a Java program (Peer) to load the "Customer" Region in the cluster. Now we want to move to Spring Data GemFire where I am not sure how to configure PDX serialization and getting...

```
com.gemstone.gemfire.InternalGemFireException: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.gemfire.poc.DomainObjects.Customer
```

`cache.xml` in simple Java program...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><cache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schema.pivotal.io/gemfire/cache" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.pivotal.io/gemfire/cache http://schema.pivotal.io/gemfire/cache/cache-8.1.xsd" version="8.1" lock-lease="120" lock-timeout="60" search-timeout="300" is-server="false" copy-on-read="false">
 <pdx>
    <pdx-serializer>
      <class-name>
       com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer
      </class-name>
    <parameter name="classes">
      <string>com.gemfire.poc.DomainObjects.*</string>
    </parameter>
  </pdx-serializer>
 </pdx>
    <region name="Customer" refid="REPLICATE">
    <region-attributes refid="REPLICATE" scope="distributed-no-ack"> 
     <cache-loader>
        <class-name>com.citigroup.pulse.pt.gemfire.poc.clientserver.SimpleCacheLoader</class-name>
    </cache-loader>
</region-attributes>
    </region>
</cache>
```

`spring-context.xml` in *Spring Boot* app...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/gemfire 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/gemfire/spring-data-gemfire.xsd">

    <util:properties id="gemfireProperties">
        <prop key="log-level">config</prop>
        <prop key="locators">hostA[10334],hostB[10334]</prop>
    </util:properties>


    <bean id="mappingPdxSerializer" class="com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer"/>

    <gfe:cache use-bean-factory-locator="false" properties-ref="gemfireProperties" use-cluster-configuration="true" pdx-serializer-ref="mappingPdxSerializer" />

    <gfe:replicated-region id="Customer" ignore-if-exists="true">       
    </gfe:replicated-region>


</beans>
```

Can someone help me fix the serialization issue?

```
Caused by: com.gemstone.gemfire.InternalGemFireException: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.gemfire.poc.DomainObjects.Customer
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.DistributionManager.putOutgoing(DistributionManager.java:1954)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.DistributedCacheOperation.distribute(DistributedCacheOperation.java:476)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.AbstractUpdateOperation.distribute(AbstractUpdateOperation.java:65)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.DistributedRegion.distributeUpdate(DistributedRegion.java:519)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.DistributedRegion.basicPutPart3(DistributedRegion.java:500)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.AbstractRegionMap.basicPut(AbstractRegionMap.java:3052)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.virtualPut(LocalRegion.java:5838)
```

Precisely, how to add "classes" parameter of `ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer` in `spring-data-gemfire` tags?

PDX deserialization exception while retrieving value from Region:

```
com.gemstone.gemfire.ToDataException: PdxSerializer failed when calling toData on class javax.management.Notification
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.writePdx(InternalDataSerializer.java:3130)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.writeUserObject(InternalDataSerializer.java:1520)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.writeWellKnownObject(InternalDataSerializer.java:1416)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.basicWriteObject(InternalDataSerializer.java:2208)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.DataSerializer.writeObject(DataSerializer.java:3181)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.util.BlobHelper.serializeToBlob(BlobHelper.java:50)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.util.BlobHelper.serializeToBlob(BlobHelper.java:38)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.UpdateOperation$UpdateMessage.toData(UpdateOperation.java:492)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.invokeToData(InternalDataSerializer.java:2407)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.writeDSFID(InternalDataSerializer.java:1378)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.tcp.MsgStreamer.writeMessage(MsgStreamer.java:239)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.direct.DirectChannel.sendToMany(DirectChannel.java:458)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.direct.DirectChannel.sendToOne(DirectChannel.java:310)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.direct.DirectChannel.send(DirectChannel.java:696)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.membership.jgroup.JGroupMembershipManager.directChannelSend(JGroupMembershipManager.java:2929)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.membership.jgroup.JGroupMembershipManager.send(JGroupMembershipManager.java:3163)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.DistributionChannel.send(DistributionChannel.java:79)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.DistributionManager.sendOutgoing(DistributionManager.java:3907)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.DistributionManager.sendMessage(DistributionManager.java:3948)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.DistributionManager.putOutgoing(DistributionManager.java:1951)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.DistributedCacheOperation.distribute(DistributedCacheOperation.java:476)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.AbstractUpdateOperation.distribute(AbstractUpdateOperation.java:65)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.DistributedRegion.distributeUpdate(DistributedRegion.java:519)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.DistributedRegion.basicPutPart3(DistributedRegion.java:500)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.ProxyRegionMap.basicPut(ProxyRegionMap.java:242)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.virtualPut(LocalRegion.java:5838)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.DistributedRegion.virtualPut(DistributedRegion.java:387)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegionDataView.putEntry(LocalRegionDataView.java:118)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.basicPut(LocalRegion.java:5228)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.validatedPut(LocalRegion.java:1599)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.put(LocalRegion.java:1582)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.AbstractRegion.put(AbstractRegion.java:327)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.ManagementResourceRepo.putEntryInLocalNotificationRegion(ManagementResourceRepo.java:169)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.NotificationHub$NotificationHubListener.handleNotification(NotificationHub.java:193)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor$ListenerWrapper.handleNotification(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1754)
    at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport.handleNotification(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:275)
    at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport$SendNotifJob.run(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:352)
    at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport$1.execute(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:337)
    at javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport.sendNotification(NotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:248)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.beans.ManagementAdapter.handleRegionRemoval(ManagementAdapter.java:879)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.beans.ManagementListener.handleEvent(ManagementListener.java:123)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.InternalDistributedSystem.notifyResourceEventListeners(InternalDistributedSystem.java:2252)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.InternalDistributedSystem.handleResourceEvent(InternalDistributedSystem.java:506)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.basicDestroyRegion(LocalRegion.java:6642)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.DistributedRegion.basicDestroyRegion(DistributedRegion.java:1957)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.LocalRegion.close(LocalRegion.java:2219)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.RegionFactoryBean.destroy(RegionFactoryBean.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:272)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1032)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$2.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:929)
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Could not write value for property protected transient java.lang.Object java.util.EventObject.source
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.mapping.MappingPdxSerializer$2.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingPdxSerializer.java:188)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.mapping.MappingPdxSerializer$2.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingPdxSerializer.java:173)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:309)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.mapping.MappingPdxSerializer.toData(MappingPdxSerializer.java:173)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.InternalDataSerializer.writePdx(InternalDataSerializer.java:3075)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.PdxFieldAlreadyExistsException: The field "source" already exists.
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.PdxType.addField(PdxType.java:262)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.PdxWriterImpl.updateMetaData(PdxWriterImpl.java:858)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.PdxWriterImpl.updateMetaData(PdxWriterImpl.java:851)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.PdxWriterImpl.writeObject(PdxWriterImpl.java:303)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.PdxWriterImpl.writeField(PdxWriterImpl.java:705)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.PdxWriterImpl.writeField(PdxWriterImpl.java:625)
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.mapping.MappingPdxSerializer$2.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingPdxSerializer.java:184)
    ... 60 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options here, along with a few suggested recommendations.

1) First, I would not use Pivotal GemFire's `o.a.g.pdx.ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer`.  Rather SDG has a much more robust `PdxSerializer` implementation based on *Spring Data's* Mapping Infrastructure (i.e. the [`o.s.d.g.mapping.MappingPdxSerializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/mapping/MappingPdxSerializer.html])).

In addition, SDG's `MappingPdxSerializer` allows you to [register custom `PdxSerializer's`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/mapping/MappingPdxSerializer.html#setCustomPdxSerializers-java.util.Map-) on an entity field/property case-by-case basis.  Imagine if your `Customer` class has a reference to a complex `Address` class and that class has special serialization needs.

Furthermore, SDG's `MappingPdxSerializer` can handle transient and read-only properties.

Finally, you don't have to mess with any fussy/complex Regex to properly identify the application domain model types that need to be serialized.

2) Second, you can leverage Spring's [JavaConfig](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java) along with SDG's **new** [Annotation-based configuration model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config) to configure Pivotal GemFire [PDX Serialization](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/developing/data_serialization/gemfire_pdx_serialization.html) as simply as this...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PeerCacheApplication
@EnablePdx(..)
class MySpringBootApacheGeodeApplication {
  ...
}
```

That is, using the SDG `@EnablePdx` annotation.

More details on #1 and #2 above are available [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-pdx) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.pdx-serializer).

Of course, the later is more applicable when using Pivotal GemFire **9.x+** with *Spring Data GemFire* **Kay** (**2.0+**).  Judging by the package in your configuration of the `com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer` from your XML config (i.e. the `com.gemstone.gemfire` package) it would appear you are using Pivotal GemFire **8.2.x** with *Spring Data GemFire* **Ingalls** (or **1.9.x.RELEASE**), perhaps?

However, if you insist on, or are required to use XML for your configuration, then you can do the following...

```
<beans ...>

  <bean id="mappingPdxSerializer" class="org.springframework.data.gemfire.mapping.MappingPdxSerializer"/>

  <gfe:cache pdx-serializer-ref="mappingPdxSerializer" .../>

</beans>
```

And, if you really want to use Pivotal GemFire's `ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer`, then you can find examples of it's use in the SDG test suite.  For [instance](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/1.9.12.RELEASE/src/test/resources/org/springframework/data/gemfire/pdxdiskstore-config.xml#L21-L29).

I also have a few more examples in my [spring-gemfire-test](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests) project/repo (which is quite a mess and I don't maintain this repo much anymore, as a warning).  Examples [here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/spring/data/gemfire/rest/GemFireRestInterfaceTest-context.xml#L23-L30), using Java configuration with GemFire's API [here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/rest/GemFireRestInterfaceTest.java#L117), [here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/ClientCacheFunctionExecutionWithPdxTest-context.xml#L28-L35), [here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/RepositoryUsingPdxSerializationTest-context.xml#L22-L29) which also shows the [use](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/RepositoryUsingPdxSerializationTest-context.xml#L33-L42) of SDG's `MappingPdxSerializer` as well (by comparison), and so on and so forth.  Many examples riddle throughout my repos.

Hope this helps!

Cheers,
-John

Comment: Thanks much for your reply. I am using Gemfire 8.2.7. On the server side, i have two xmls cache.xml and spring-context where PDX is mentioned in cache.xml. Spring-data-gemfire version is 1.6 as it came along with 8.2.7.  @EnablePDX is not available in SDG 1.6 i think. How does mappingPdxSerializer know which object to be serialized?.

Comment: I tried with mappingPdxSerializer in both cluster and my java program, it worked. I am able to persist the data into Region from my java peer. Thanks much. But i am getting following exception while deserializing  and retrieving , Can you explain why?.  Caused by: com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.PdxFieldAlreadyExistsException: The field "source" already exists.
 at com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.PdxType.addField(PdxType.java:262)

Comment: Update the post with full stack trace of exception. All i have done is created a gemfire-config jar with domain objects (POJO without @Region ) and using the same in both server and peer.

Comment: Spring Data for Pivotal GemFire 1.6 reached EOL some time ago.  The latest/current version of SDG supporting Pivotal GemFire 8.2.x is SDG 1.9.12.RELEASE, which is based on the latest version of Pivotal GemFire 8.2, i.e. 8.2.11.  What happens when you try the newest versions?

Comment: You may also use the following reference as a guide for evaluating the latest/current versions in order to stay up-to-date... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/wiki/Spring-Data-GemFire-to-GemFire-Version-Compatibility.

Comment: On a related note, I think you could possibly be running into this problem (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-4822).  NOTE: Apache Geode is the open source core of Pivotal GemFire.  Since there currently is no capability in SDG's `o.s.d.g.mapping.MappingPdxSerializer` to filter on what types actually are handled and get de/serialized (i.e. all types passing through the serializer as determined by GemFire/Geode will be de/serialized) I have been contemplating adding support for filtering types, such as by the package where your application entities live, for instance.

Comment: NOTE: the non-type filtering capabilities in SDG's `MappingPdxSerializer` is unlike GemFire/Geode's `ReflectionBasedAutoSerialzier`, which does accept a Regex pattern to filter types that the serializer is directly responsible for handling.  I am also uncertain whether 8.2.11 has a fix for GEODE-4822, or even whether it will.  Please test with these versions though, i.e. SDG 1.9.12.RELEASE and Pivotal GemFire 8.2.11 (which is pulled in by SDG 1.9.12).  In the meantime, I have filed SGF-745 (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-745) for your reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170922/discussion-between-sudharsan-and-john-blum).